# rqt package segmentaion fault

Tags: ros-kinetic, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

when I am trying to run any node from the rqt package I am getting a segmentation fault:

[15:54:27]~:

> rosrun rqt_gui rqt_gui

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

[15:54:49]~:

> rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I am running ros kinetic on ubuntu 16.04

Thank you in advance for your help!

**One Solution** I found, for future reference:
I was able to call these functions by just calling

> rqt

or

> rqt_graph

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352342/rqt-package-segmentaion-fault/) by [Timbotic](https://answers.ros.org/users/54914/timbotic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2020-05-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-05-14**:
Do you have a non-default version of Qt / sip installed?

**Comment by [Timbotic](https://answers.ros.org/users/54914/timbotic/) on 2020-05-15**:
No and thank you for trying to help, I actually was able to circumvent the problem by just calling

> rqt_graph

which worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay now I found the real problem! There seemed to be some python version issue. I also had anaconda installed, which I deleted since I dont need it anymore and reinstalled python and ros-kinetic, which solved the problem.

This also seems to be the reason for getting an error when trying to call

> rospack depends1 [Packagename]

---

Originally posted by [Timbotic](https://answers.ros.org/users/54914/timbotic/) with karma: 26 on 2020-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0